# Highcharts stock-tools Clicks Causing ASP.NET Postback?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, highcharts

I am working on implementing the Highcharts [stock-tool](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/stock-tools) GUI into our stock charts. The GUI appears and the data is present in the chart. However, any click on a button from the stock-tools (such as adding an indicator) forces a page postback. I do not want it to postback - it should just add the indicator, flag, and any other annotation.

I have one button on the page that is a .NET postback (to go fetch the data set). All other client side buttons work as expected (sorting data, exporting flat files, or exporting image of chart).

How can I prevent this postback?

**Update**:
This is [bug](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12090) caused by accessibility module as reported on github.

Comment: Do you use Highcharts .NET or only JS library?

Comment: I am only using the JS libraries. I am building the chart from a table on the page.

Comment: So could you try to reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I am not able to create a jsFiddle as it just runs javascript. If i take the demo code for the stock tool and load it up in my ASP.NET application clicking "add" for creating a trend series (like SMA) just reloads the entire page as if a postback occurred.

Comment: In that case could you send me a package with a project that will present this issue?